# Long text in ssrs report viewer pushes column past end of table

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportviewer

I have a column in my ssrs report which holds a long text field, such as "notes".  In the designer and in preview mode, even on export to excel and pdf, it looks fine.  However, in the report viewer on an asp.net page, it pushes the containing column far beyond the defined width of the column.  Any ideas how to make it not do this, or will I break something in the export if I alter the rendered text somehow?

Comment: have you try for `CanGrow` property of column.

Comment: Yes, I've set it to true and tested, then to false and tested.  Same issue either way.

Comment: CanGrow property only works on cell height

Comment: This is happenning to me too, but at Word. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Insert a rectangle first inside the column cell then the text box for your data.